# Internationalization of task comments using Camunda rest-engine

Tags: tomcat, camunda, business-process-management

I setup Camunda as a web-service in tomcat and connect to it via my .NET web application.
When I create comment on task with following rest API

POST /task/{id}/comment/create

with message in Unicode (Persian), for example “این نمونه است”
and I got the correct message in response request. Also the comment is saved in persian correctly in the camunda database.
But when I get the comment using this API

GET /task/{id}/comment/{commentId}

I got message as “?? ???”
I tried it with postman and got same result.
I also set the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" in tomcat but it does not solve it.
I am wonder what is the root of problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to responses of @hassang and @davidgs in [Camunda community](https://forum.camunda.org/t/internationalization-of-task-commnets-using-camunda-rest-engine/31347/4),

it looks like a bug in the get request of /comment sub-resource which I file a bug [Camunda GitHub repository](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform) as follows:

https://jira.camunda.com/browse/CAM-14125

Answer (score 0):

it looks like [Comment Full Message longblob UTF-8](https://groups.google.com/g/camunda-bpm-users/c/c78oP4wtCLE)

my solution is (in Canmunda 7.16.0 、camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter) :

```java
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.TaskServiceImpl;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.AbstractProcessEnginePlugin;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.AddCommentCmd;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.DbSqlSessionFactory;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.CommentEntity;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntity;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.ClockUtil;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.task.Comment;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.task.Event;
import org.springframework.security.util.InMemoryResource;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.EnsureUtil.ensureNotNull;

/**
 * Change the 160character limit of the message, and blob uses UTF8 codec
 *
 * @see <a href="https://groups.google.com/g/camunda-bpm-users/c/c78oP4wtCLE">Comment FullMessage longblob UTF-8</a>
 */
public class UTF8CommentPlugin extends AbstractProcessEnginePlugin {
    @Override
    public void preInit(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl processEngineConfiguration) {
        processEngineConfiguration.setTaskService(new UTF8CommentTaskService());
        processEngineConfiguration.getDbEntityCacheKeyMapping().registerEntityCacheKey(UTF8CommentEntity.class, CommentEntity.class);
    }

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public void postInit(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl processEngineConfiguration) {
        // org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.DbSqlSessionFactory.getInsertStatement. 
        // org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.DbSqlSessionFactory.getStatement uses the insert prefix + CommentEntity to remove Entity as a mybatis mapping, such as [insertComment]. 
        // then through mybatis SqlSession through direct use of statementId= [insertComment]. 
        // (statementId of normal mapper is org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.SqlCommand.resolveMappedStatement) = = mapperInterface.getName () + "." + methodName = = xml namespace + "." + sqlId. 
        // but because of the way iBatis is left behind, if the mybatis xml sql statement id is globally unique, you can also use the statement id directly. 
        // so you must add the mapping manually or it will not correspond to the correct sql statement. 
        // the sql file is located in org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.mapping.entity.Comment.xml
        DbSqlSessionFactory dbSqlSessionFactory = processEngineConfiguration.getDbSqlSessionFactory();
        dbSqlSessionFactory.getInsertStatements().put(UTF8CommentEntity.class, "insertComment");
        // add a replacement sql
        Map<String, String> statementMappings = dbSqlSessionFactory.getStatementMappings();
        InputStream inputStream = new InMemoryResource(UTF_8_COMMENT_XML).getInputStream();
        Configuration configuration = processEngineConfiguration.getSqlSessionFactory().getConfiguration();
        XMLMapperBuilder xmlParser = new XMLMapperBuilder(inputStream, configuration, getClass().getCanonicalName(), configuration.getSqlFragments());
        xmlParser.parse();
        // add sql statementId mapping to map the statementId in org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.CommentManager.findCommentsByTaskId to our
        statementMappings.put("selectCommentsByTaskId", "selectCommentsByTaskId_UTF8");
        statementMappings.put("selectCommentsByProcessInstanceId", "selectCommentsByProcessInstanceId_UTF8");
        statementMappings.put("selectCommentByTaskIdAndCommentId", "selectCommentByTaskIdAndCommentId_UTF8");
    }

    private static class UTF8CommentTaskService extends TaskServiceImpl {

        @Override
        public Comment createComment(String taskId, String processInstance, String message) {
            return commandExecutor.execute(new UTF8AddCommentCmd(taskId, processInstance, message));
        }
    }

    private static class UTF8AddCommentCmd extends AddCommentCmd {

        public UTF8AddCommentCmd(String taskId, String processInstanceId, String message) {
            super(taskId, processInstanceId, message);
        }

        @Override
        public Comment execute(CommandContext commandContext) {

            if (processInstanceId == null && taskId == null) {
                throw new ProcessEngineException("Process instance id and task id is null");
            }

            ensureNotNull("Message", message);

            String userId = commandContext.getAuthenticatedUserId();
            CommentEntity comment = new UTF8CommentEntity();
            comment.setUserId(userId);
            comment.setType(CommentEntity.TYPE_COMMENT);
            comment.setTime(ClockUtil.getCurrentTime());
            comment.setTaskId(taskId);
            comment.setProcessInstanceId(processInstanceId);
            comment.setAction(Event.ACTION_ADD_COMMENT);

            ExecutionEntity execution = getExecution(commandContext);
            if (execution != null) {
                comment.setRootProcessInstanceId(execution.getRootProcessInstanceId());
            }

            if (isHistoryRemovalTimeStrategyStart()) {
                provideRemovalTime(comment);
            }

            String eventMessage = message.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
            //this may be a little too much, change it to the length you need.
            if (eventMessage.length() > 3000) {
                eventMessage = eventMessage.substring(0, 3000) + "...";
            }
            comment.setMessage(eventMessage);

            comment.setFullMessage(message);

            commandContext
                    .getCommentManager()
                    .insert(comment);

            TaskEntity task = getTask(commandContext);
            if (task != null) {
                task.triggerUpdateEvent();
            }

            return comment;
        }
    }

    public static class UTF8CommentEntity extends CommentEntity {
        @Override
        public byte[] getFullMessageBytes() {
            return (fullMessage != null ? fullMessage.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) : null);
        }

        @Override
        public void setFullMessageBytes(byte[] fullMessageBytes) {
            fullMessage = (fullMessageBytes != null ? new String(fullMessageBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) : null);
        }
    }

    private final static String UTF_8_COMMENT_XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
            "<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC \"-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN\" \"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd\">\n" +
            "<mapper namespace=\"" + UTF8CommentPlugin.class.getName() + "\">\n" +
            "    <resultMap id=\"commentResultMap\" type=\""+UTF8CommentEntity.class.getName()+"\">\n" +
            "        <id property=\"id\" column=\"ID_\" jdbcType=\"VARCHAR\"/>\n" +
            "        <result property=\"type\" column=\"TYPE_\" jdbcType=\"VARCHAR\"/>\n" +
            "        <result property=\"userId\" column=\"USER_ID_\" jdbcType=\"VARCHAR\"/>\n" +
            "        <result property=\"time\" column=\"TIME_\" jdbcType=\"TIMESTAMP\"/>\n" +
            "        <result property=\"taskId\" column=\"TASK_ID_\" jdbcType=\"VARCHAR\"/>\n" +
            "        <result property=\"rootProcessInstanceId\" column=\"ROOT_PROC_INST_ID_\" jdbcType=\"VARCHAR\"/>\n" +
            "        <result property=\"processInstanceId\" column=\"PROC_INST_ID_\" jdbcType=\"VARCHAR\"/>\n" +
            "        <result property=\"action\" column=\"ACTION_\" jdbcType=\"VARCHAR\"/>\n" +
            "        <result property=\"message\" column=\"MESSAGE_\" jdbcType=\"VARCHAR\"/>\n" +
            "        <result property=\"fullMessageBytes\" column=\"FULL_MSG_\" jdbcType=\"BLOB\"/>\n" +
            "        <result property=\"tenantId\" column=\"TENANT_ID_\" jdbcType=\"VARCHAR\"/>\n" +
            "        <result property=\"removalTime\" column=\"REMOVAL_TIME_\" jdbcType=\"TIMESTAMP\"/>\n" +
            "    </resultMap>\n" +
            "    <select id=\"selectCommentsByTaskId_UTF8\" parameterType=\"org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.ListQueryParameterObject\"\n" +
            "            resultMap=\"commentResultMap\">\n" +
            "        select *\n" +
            "        from ${prefix}ACT_HI_COMMENT\n" +
            "        where TASK_ID_ = #{parameter,jdbcType=VARCHAR}\n" +
            "          and TYPE_ = 'comment'\n" +
            "        order by TIME_ desc\n" +
            "    </select>\n" +
            "    <select id=\"selectCommentsByProcessInstanceId_UTF8\"\n" +
            "            parameterType=\"org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.ListQueryParameterObject\" resultMap=\"commentResultMap\">\n" +
            "        select *\n" +
            "        from ${prefix}ACT_HI_COMMENT\n" +
            "        where PROC_INST_ID_ = #{parameter,jdbcType=VARCHAR}\n" +
            "        order by TIME_ desc\n" +
            "    </select>\n" +
            "    <select id=\"selectCommentByTaskIdAndCommentId_UTF8\" parameterType=\"map\" resultMap=\"commentResultMap\">\n" +
            "        select *\n" +
            "        from ${prefix}ACT_HI_COMMENT\n" +
            "        where TASK_ID_ = #{taskId,jdbcType=VARCHAR}\n" +
            "          and ID_ = #{id,jdbcType=VARCHAR}\n" +
            "    </select>\n" +
            "</mapper>";
}
```

and register this plug-in with spring

```java
@Bean
UTF8CommentPlugin utf8CommentPlugin() {
    return new UTF8CommentPlugin();
}
```